# VBA Access the button on the form working (only once) ater that its not responding

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-office

VBA Access the button on the form working (only once) ater that its not responding
no errors in debug and , no error massages in the procedure or function
sorry for my bad english.

#Im a new in VBA 2 weeks only but i know C++ and C then i understand somehow the code.

Information what office i use and what i done:

#I tried to change settings in Trust Relationship Center but no luck.

#I want it will run in office access 2007.

#The code is Written in VBA office access 2000 im now useing office 365 to edit the project but its not working in 2007 or 2003 either.

#tested if  form remaining  opened when i have problem but all closed and no remainings

how it works:
you click this

[image: First form]

#######################################################################################

after the click we see this form Now we have problem here with the button
this button on the form only works once after thet not responding

[image: The second form]

here is the code of the 2 buttons

####This code for the first picture:

```
Private Sub OpenCust_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_OpenCust_Click

Dim stDocName As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String


stDocName = "cust"
Me.RecNo = Me.CurrentRecord
stLinkCriteria = "[CustNo]=" & Me![CustNo]
DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria, acFormEdit

MsgBox "getted out from opencust" 'its ok working

Exit_OpenCust_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_OpenCust_Click:
   MsgBox Err.Description
   Resume Exit_OpenCust_Click

'the code not getting here No matter what
End Sub
```

---

####This code for the second picture:

```
Private Sub NewTsiyud_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_NewTsiyud_Click


Dim stDocName As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String


stDocName = "ShirutTsiyud"
'the stLinkCriteria is not effecting if i take down it

DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria, acFormAdd

Form_cust![TiyudimCust].Requery
  
MsgBox "getted out from newTsiyud" 'this is working only once
    

Exit_NewTsiyud_Click:
  Exit Sub

Err_NewTsiyud_Click:
  MsgBox Err.Description
  Resume Exit_NewTsiyud_Click

End Sub
```

---

Edit:
Kostas K -Gave me a good direction and I now on it I found what makes the problem of the forms but still I trying to fix it thanks to everyone :-)

Comment: Could it be that open the for append only: `DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria, acFormAdd`?

Comment: can you explain more? i didn't understand what you mean   , test with acFormEdit it didnt work either

Comment: OK. Then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the button click sub and then step in each line of code with F8 to see where it hangs.

Comment: Wow thx now i found another procedure that working with the current procedure and  the breaking point not worked until i ALLOW ACCESS SPECIAL KEYS in the settings